# как вывести циклом нужные данные элементов массива php в html-таблицу?

Tags: php, html, массивы

пример массива $elements:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Стабилизаторы напряжения
            [h1] => Стабилизаторы напряжения
            [parentId] => NULL

        )
 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 192
            [name] => GMGen Power Systems
            [h1] => Бензиновые и дизельные генераторы
            [parentId] => 125

        )
    ...
)
```

как вывести циклом нужные данные всех элементов массива php в html-таблицу, как это реализовано с одним элементом массива ниже

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Заголовок</th>
          <th>ID родителя</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr> 
         <td><?=$elements[0]['id']?></th>
         <td><?=$elements[0]['h1']?></th>
         <td><?=$elements[0]['parentId']?></th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы циклы не умеете писать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($elements as $element): ?>
    <tr> 
        <td><?= $element['id']; ?></th>
        <td><?= $element['h1']; ?></th>
        <td><?= $element['parentId'] ?? 'Родитель отсутствует'; ?></th>
    </tr>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```